# If $ B(X) \ni \{T_n\} \to T $ invertible with $\|T_n^{−1}\|<1$ , then $T$ is invertible

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, solution-verification

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and suppose that $\{T_n\}$ is a sequence of invertible operators in $B(X)$ which converges to $T \in B(X)$. Suppose also that $\|T_n^{−1}\|<1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that $T$ is invertible.

**My attempt:**

> *Thm* : Let $H$ be a real Hilbert space. Let $A : H \to H$ be a bounded linear operator which is
>   strictly positive definite, so that $\exists \ \beta >0 \ \ s.t. \langle A x,x\rangle \ge \beta \|x\|^2$. Then, for every $f \in H$, there exists a unique $u = A^{−1}f \in H$ such that $Au = f$ (i.e. $A$ is invertible) .
>   The inverse operator $A^{−1}$ satisfies   $\|A^{−1}\|\le \frac{1}{\beta}$.

$(1)$ Since $T_n$ is is invertible for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$,  $\exists \ \beta >0 \ \ s.t. \langle T_n x,x\rangle \ge \beta \|x\|^2$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Since $\|T_n^{−1}\|<1 \implies \beta =1$.

$(2)$ Since $T_n \in B(X) , \ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ By uniform boundedness principle they're uniformly bounded and the limit $T$ is also linear and bounded.

$(3)$ Since $T,T_n \in B(X) , \ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ ,  there exists a subsequence $T_{nk}\rightharpoonup T$ i.e. $\langle T_{nk}x,x\rangle \to \langle Tx,x\rangle $,  as $k\to \infty, \ \forall x \in H$.

So from part (1) we have the $ \langle Tx,x\rangle  = \lim_{k\to \infty} \langle T_{nk}x,x\rangle \ge \|x\|^2$.

Comment: Do you think any invertible matrix is semi-definite? Your assumption in (1) is false.

Comment: an Invertible matrix $T$ is strictly positive definite, I am following "lecture notes in functional analysis, by bressan" this inequality has been given as the definition of strictly positive definite operator $T$. [page 89]

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy , is the above comment correct?

Comment: A diagonal matrix with strictly negative diagonal entries is invertible but it is not positive definite.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true that invertibility of $T_n$ gives you the inequality you stated in (1). So this method completely breaks down.

Note that $\|I-T_n^{-1}T\|=\|T_n^{-1}T_n-T_n^{-1}T\|\leq \|T_n^{-1}\|\|T_n-T\| <1$ for $n$ sufficiently large. From  the following well known fact it follows that $T_n^{-1}T$ is invertible and hence $T=T_n T_n^{-1}T$ is also invertible.

Lemma: If $S$ is a bounded operator with $\|S\| <1$ then $I-S$ is invertible

The lemma is proved by showing that the series $\sum S^{n}$ converges in operator norm and its sum is the inverse of $I-S$.

Comment: You should take the sum $\sum_n S^n$, not $\sum (I-S)^n$. Also, in your identity from the start it should be $T_n^{-1}T_n$ instead of $T_n^{-1} T$.

Comment: @PhoemueX Thanks you. Corrected both the mistakes.